# With Lucene 4.3.1, How to get all terms which occur in sub-range of all docs

Tags: lucene

Suppose a lucene index with fields : date, content.
I want to get all terms value and frequency of docs whose date is yesterday. date field is keyword field. content field is analyzed and indexed.

Pls help me with sample code.

Comment: Show the code you've tried already ?

Comment: I can extract full terms by ... Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(searcher.getIndexReader()); Terms terms = fields.terms("content"); TermsEnum eachTerm = terms.iterator(null);

Comment: My temporary solution is 1. get docid which has certain date range, 2. analyze each document and make word frequency by program 3. sort the frequency 4. get top-n word. Are there any other solution with lucene api only? pls let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution source is as follow ...

```
/**
 * 
 * 
 * @param reader
 * @param fromDateTime
 *            - yyyymmddhhmmss 
 * @param toDateTime
 *            - yyyymmddhhmmss 
 * @return 
 */
static public String top10(IndexSearcher searcher, String fromDateTime,
        String toDateTime) {
    String top10Query = "";
    try {
        Query query = new TermRangeQuery("tweetDate", new BytesRef(
                fromDateTime), new BytesRef(toDateTime), true, false);
        final BitSet bits = new BitSet(searcher.getIndexReader().maxDoc());
        searcher.search(query, new Collector() {

            private int docBase;

            @Override
            public void setScorer(Scorer scorer) throws IOException {
            }

            @Override
            public void setNextReader(AtomicReaderContext context)
                    throws IOException {
                this.docBase = context.docBase;
            }

            @Override
            public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
                bits.set(doc + docBase);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean acceptsDocsOutOfOrder() {
                return false;
            }
        });

        //
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43,
                EnglishStopWords.getEnglishStopWords());

        //
        HashMap<String, Long> wordFrequency = new HashMap<>();
        for (int wx = 0; wx < bits.length(); ++wx) {
            if (bits.get(wx)) {
                Document wd = searcher.doc(wx);
                //
                TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("temp",
                        new StringReader(wd.get("content")));
                // OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = tokenStream
                // .addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
                CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream
                        .addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
                tokenStream.reset();
                while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
                    // int startOffset = offsetAttribute.startOffset();
                    // int endOffset = offsetAttribute.endOffset();
                    String term = charTermAttribute.toString();
                    if (term.length() < 2)
                        continue;
                    Long wl;
                    if ((wl = wordFrequency.get(term)) == null)
                        wordFrequency.put(term, 1L);
                    else {
                        wl += 1;
                        wordFrequency.put(term, wl);
                    }
                }
                tokenStream.end();
                tokenStream.close();
            }
        }
        analyzer.close();

        // sort
        List<String> occurterm = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String ws : wordFrequency.keySet()) {
            occurterm.add(String.format("%06d\t%s", wordFrequency.get(ws),
                    ws));
        }
        Collections.sort(occurterm, Collections.reverseOrder());

        // make query string by top 10 words
        int topCount = 10;
        for (String ws : occurterm) {
            if (topCount-- == 0)
                break;
            String[] tks = ws.split("\\t");
            top10Query += tks[1] + " ";
        }
        top10Query.trim();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
    // return top10 word string
    return top10Query;
}
```